# Search filter by name and date in React Redux Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, antd

I'm currently learning about react, more specifically about typescript and redux. I need to make a search filter with name and date. I made a date filter with RangePicker by antd(with hooks), but I don't know how to make one with a name.

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string[]>([]);
  <Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
    <RangePicker onChange={(dates, datesString) => {setSearchTerm(datesString)}}/>
  </Space>
  <Table 
    className='tablica' 
    columns={columns} 
    dataSource={todoHistory.filter((val) => {
      if(searchTerm.length > 0){
        if(moment(val.datum).diff(searchTerm[0]) >= 0 && 
          moment(val.datum).diff(searchTerm[1]) <= 0 ) {
          return val
        }
      }else{ return val; }
    )} 
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you need is by creating another `state` to hold the `name` that will be used to filter, and use it in the `todoHistory.filter`.

```js
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [name, setName] = useState('');

<input value={name} onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />

<Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
  <RangePicker onChange={(dates, datesString) => {setSearchTerm(datesString)}}/>
</Space>

<Table 
  className='tablica' 
  columns={columns} 
  dataSource={todoHistory
    .filter((val) => {
      if(searchTerm.length > 0) {
        return moment(val.datum).diff(searchTerm[0]) >= 0 &&
               moment(val.datum).diff(searchTerm[1]) <= 0;
      }
    
      return true;
    })
   .filter((val) => {
      /* replace val.name with your attribute name */
      return val.name.includes(name);
    })
  } 
/>
```

Note that I've changed the implementation of the first filter to return a `boolean`, as it is more accurate with what the `filter` is expecting to be returned. [filter docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters)

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually managed to solve this problem through useEffect hook but your answer helped too.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem through useEffect hook and creating another state.
So I created another state:

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
```

And then useEffect hook:

```
    useEffect(() => { console.log(searchText);
setTodoHistory(todoHistory.filter((todoItem) => {
    if(todoItem.naziv?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())){
      return todoItem;
    }
}))
```

},[searchText]);

And then I made an Input:

```
   <Input className="search-text" placeholder='Search...' type='text' onChange={event => {setSearchText(event.target.value)}}/>
```